# How to reinstall windows without usb?

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, virus, format

I have a computer full of viruses (well actually my cousin has).
I want to delete windows 7 and reinstall it.

Is it possible to do it without a windows iso file?

I also have an ubuntu iso on my hard disk but I don't want to connect it to the infected computer because I am worried that it may transfer some of the viruses on that device.

Comment: OP was not asking about a network install but a way to Download the OS ISO, like you can with Apple.

Comment: @Moab, then why does OP write `Is it possible to do it without a windows iso file? ` - seems they do not want an ISO...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install from USB. You can also install from DVD.

You can use the original DVD and install it from that. Or, download the Windows 7 DVD and use that. Either way, Windows 7 DVD (just make sure the version matches, such as pro or ultimate etc).

See a place to get the ISO to put it onto the DVD - http://mirror.corenoc.de/digitalrivercontent.net/

Comment: ah thanks! But is it possible to do it from online? With mac os x for example you can download it and install it on the fly

Comment: These links are long dead. The images are still available [here](http://mirror.corenoc.de/digitalrivercontent.net/).

Comment: @Ant - If the license is a non-OEM license you can download Windows 7 using the Microsoft provided tool.  Windows 7 does not offer the capability you describe, Windows 10 does, versions prior to the most recent and supported versions of OS X, also do not.  In all cases you still need installation media, so you might as well, just do it the easy way.